# Эффекты. Очередь Эффектов .queue()

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет.

```
    <div class="red">
    </div>
    <div class="blue" style="background-color:blue">
    </div>
    <script>
        $("div.red").hide().show().fadeOut(100).fadeIn(5000);

    var fx1=$("div.red").queue();
    console.log(fx1);    //["inprogress", function()] //что такое inprogress?

    //console.log(fx1.length)//2
   // console.log(fx1.pop())//Удаление последней функции

  $("div.blue").queue(fx1);
    </script>
```

Как получить очередь анимации заданного элемента (`div.red`), удалить последнюю анимацию  и добавить в произвольный порядок выполнения(например под номером 2) произвольную функцию и повесить очередность на новый элемент (например `div.blue`)?

Какие функции попадают в этот список? Почему `hide().show()` не попадают?

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите сказать, что даже не окинули взглядом [официальное описание метода](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)? Или просто лень переводить? Разберите их [пример с комментариями на русском](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/RdPbx/).

Comment: Извените,но я только вижу как добавить функцию в стэк вызовов анимаций/остановить анимацию.А копировать анимации с одного элемента на другой нету.